# Bind similar but disparate user controls as a collection

Tags: wpf, observablecollection

I'm working a touch based WPF UI that consists of multiple user controls that are disparate and not a collection, on a page . Each control has a name, address and phone number. I would like to encapsulate these controls into a control that allows me to select an item so that I can bind the set of controls collectively to a collection and bind the individuals to an object representing it. How can I go about doing that (preferably with minimal or no code behind)? Thanks in advance

```
 <common:StudentInfoUsrCtrl x:Name="Stud01" Margin="680,320,323,960" />
 <common:StudentInfoUsrCtrl x:Name="Stud02" Margin="844,534,159,746"     TouchUp="Stud02_TouchUp" />
 <common:StudentInfoUsrCtrl x:Name="Stud03" Margin="926,748,77,532" />
```

Comment: Elaborate (change) this sentence to provide more of what is needed: "bind the set of controls collectively to a collection and bind the individuals to an object representing it.". How does the *master* control know where the individual items from the collection bind to which control? More info needed...it is not clear on what is actually wanted.

Comment: Because you want a collection of objects and a selected object, you probably want to use a `ListBox`. So create a collection of your object models (yes in code behind - these are data items, not UI items), bind the collection to a ListBox.ItemsSource and bind the SelectedItem. Now you can update the UI templates to draw the items however you want, while maintaining your data separately in a way that is logical for data to be manipulated and handled.